# Error en Formula en Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo una pequeña duda al momento de ingresar el rpt en el crystal report viewer me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al abrir el reporte y realizar la vista previa del informe procedo a ingresar los valores correspondientes a evaluar **01/01/2020 y 31/01/2020** y no me arroja error alguno.

El problema reside al momento de añadir en el crystal Report Viewer, adjunto la formula que entre comillas es al momento de evaluar el mes que presenta el problema.

```
CStr(Day({?@FECHAI}),0,'') & ' AL ' & CStr(DAY({?@FECHAF}),0,'') & ' DE ' & UpperCase( MonthName( Month({?@FECHAF}))) & ' DE ' & CStr(YEAR({?@FECHAF}),0,'')
```

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También podrías hacerlo de esta manera, usando `ToText`

```
totext(Day({?@FECHAI}}),0)  & ' AL ' & totext(Day({?@FECHAF}}),0) & ' DE ' & 
UpperCase(MonthName(Month({?@FECHAF}))) & ' DE ' & totext(year({?@FECHAF}),0,'')
```

> Esto asumiendo que realmente tus parámetros: `@FECHAI` y `@FECHAF` son de tipo `Date` o `DateTime`

Prueba y me dejas saber tu resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Utilicé tu fórmula en Visual Studio 2013 y la modifiqué con la siguiente por algunos errores de versión:

```
=CStr(Day(Parameters!FECHAI.Value)) & " AL " & CStr(DAY(Parameters!FECHAF.Value)) & " DE " & UCase(MonthName(Month(Parameters!FECHAF.Value))) & " DE " & CStr(YEAR(Parameters!FECHAF.Value))
```

Al momento de ejecutar el reporte e ingresar las fechas **01/01/2020 y 31/01/2020** se imprime lo siguiente:

**1 AL 31 DE ENERO DE 2020**

Comment: Al momento de usar la formula y verificar si no tiene errores me arroja que falta el ). en Parameters , la versión que se usa es la de crystal report para visual studio 10